# How to see Memory Mapping in Gem5 fs mode?

Tags: linux, operating-system, gem5

I am using gem5 with DRAMSim2 and want to analyze memory mapping in gem5. How is memory mapping of DRAMSim2 associated with memory mapping of gem5? I have already seen /proc/iomem. I just want to know options to analyze memory mapping in gem5 with or without DRAMSim2.

Comment: Hi Prakhar, just to understand better since I'm a beginner: what you want is given a raw physical CPU address, what DRAM address it maps to, is that correct? And then in theory the only thing you need to know is what is the base address of the `DRAMSim2`?

Comment: Yes, i want to see how this mapping is done. How is memory mapped?